# How tu run junit test suite multiple times with different WebDriver configuration

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am using junit to run test on website with Selenium webdriver. What I am trying to achieve is to run same test class multiple times but every time I want to change my login credentials for website so it can be tested with different access permissions. I dont know how to approach this problem.

I am using TestSuite class to specify which test classes should be runned and WebDriver is being initialized in TestRunner class

testSuite class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        DhcpReservationTest.class,
})

public class TestSuite {
}
```

TestRunner class:

```
public class TestRunner {
    /**
     * Init web driver
     */
    private static WebDriver driver = DriverManager.createDriver(ProjectSettings.Roles.NETADMIN);

    /**
     * This static method serves for getting instance of web driver for executing tests.
     * @return web driver
     */
    public static WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    static JUnitCore junitCore;
    static Class<?> testClasses;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Running Junit Test Suite.");

        junitCore = new JUnitCore();

        junitCore.addListener(new CustomExecutionListener());

        Result result = junitCore.run(TestSuite.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Successful: " + result.wasSuccessful() + " ran " + result.getRunCount() + " tests");
    }
}
```

The goal is to change permission role in TestRunner when initializing webdriver from "NETADMIN" to e.g. "SYSADMIN" etc. everytime when tests are completed and run the same test suite again.

Is there some way how to do it or should I approach this differently? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not good in Java, but I have done similar thing in C# and Nunit. 
I had all my test methods in a parent class. And had multiple derived classes, which implement the method holding the difference.

So you have something like that (pseudocode):

```
parentClass{
  [Test]
  testMethod1(){
    login();
    //test things
  }
  [Test]
  testMethod2(){
    login();
    //test other things
  }   
}
[TestSuite]
subclass1()<<parentClass{
  login(){
    //do first type of login
  }
}
subclass2()<<parentClass{
  login(){
    //do second type of login
  }
}
```

So tests are executed within the 2 derived classes, but they inherit all the test methods from the parent class. There will be probably some details that I miss, but this was my approach.

Actually I had the difference in a beforeEach methods in the derived classes, but I guess the above would be very similar.